# Azure Caching - "server collection cannot be empty"

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-caching

I have a single Web Role, using MVC5.

In web role properties I selected Enable Caching.

In a controller in my MVC app I have:

```
 var cache = new DataCache("default");
```

But it throws an error:

```
"Server collection cannot be empty"
```

Is the controller the wrong place to create the cache object? I was just trying to put it where I might have used a session cache before.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't actually configured your application to point to the cache server that was set up for you.

[Here are instructions to do it via .config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278346.aspx).

[Here are instructions to do it programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618003.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Drew. Is there such a thing as a development cache, in the same way as I can use development settings for tables and blob storage? I'm just finding my feet with Azure and can't afford a full account, so trying to do as much as possible in a local environment.

Comment: No there isn't AFAIK. You would need to create a separate cache instance in Azure to dev against... either that or create a diff. cache name to against in the same instance, but beware that you would be competing with resources for your production cache entries then.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to make any code changes, you have two options.

1) Use In Role Caching mechanism and configure the application - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx

2) Use Azure Cache Service - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/30/instant-azure-caching-with-mvc.aspx. There is also sample code in MSDN - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Caching-78a49b70

In either the cases you need to configure the application's web.config and still go ahead and use Session state.